# Как из функции IIFE показать переменную в глобальной области?

Tags: javascript

Привет,я начинающий js разраб. У меня появился вопрос, на который я сам не могу ответить, подскажите как должен выглядеть код.
Необходимо, чтобы переменная внутри функции IIFE показывалась в глобальной области видимости, при этом она должна оставаться в локальной области видимости функции.
Вот пример:

```
(function() {
var photoObjects = [];
})();
```

Comment: Какую задачу решает?

Comment: Переменная должна быть в функции IIFE, но и видна в глобальной области

Comment: Если переменная глобальная, то она видна во всех функциях

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
window.photoObjects = [];
```

или

```
photoObjects = []; // без var - не в strict режиме
```

или

```
var photoObjects = [];
(function() {
  photoObjects.push(123);
})();
```

Comment: почему без var? объявление переменной должно же быть?

Comment: чтобы сделать `photoObjects` свойством глобального объекта `window`

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, все работает)

Comment: @Igor Без `var` можно отгрести в `use strict`. Так, что первый вариант лучше

Comment: @AntonShchyrov А c `window` можно огрести там, где нет никакого `window`, например в NodeJS. Так что только 3-й вариант. :)